# Avoid creating debug info in LKM with kbuild

Tags: gcc, makefile, linux-device-driver, kbuild

I'm building Linux kernel module (LKM) from a big C files (>50 000 LOC). It's some generated RAID calculation code. When I try to build it from kbuild gcc eats all of the memory and crashes, while invoking gcc manually works fine.

After inspecting object files from manual gcc and kbuild I've found that kbuild object files is 20-30 times larger than manual gcc objects (900k vs 30M). And the reason is that kbuild object files contains giant section debug_info with tons of data.

Here is the fragment from `objdump -x`:

```
RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.debug_info]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE 
0000000000000006 R_X86_64_32       .debug_abbrev
000000000000000c R_X86_64_32       .debug_str+0x0000000000000c41
0000000000000011 R_X86_64_32       .debug_str+0x0000000000000e26
0000000000000015 R_X86_64_32       .debug_str+0x0000000000000544
0000000000000019 R_X86_64_64       .text 
0000000000000021 R_X86_64_64       .text+0x0000000000060957
0000000000000029 R_X86_64_32       .debug_line
0000000000000030 R_X86_64_32       .debug_str+0x0000000000000b78
0000000000000037 R_X86_64_32       .debug_str+0x000000000000011e
0000000000000040 R_X86_64_32       .debug_str+0x000000000000066b
0000000000000047 R_X86_64_32       .debug_str+0x0000000000000d38
000000000000004e R_X86_64_32       .debug_str+0x0000000000000bef
                  ... another 60000 records ...
00000000000a0c8d R_X86_64_32       .debug_str+0x0000000000000add
00000000000a0ca0 R_X86_64_32       .debug_str+0x0000000000000526
00000000000a0cae R_X86_64_64       Calculation_1s_Func_Buf
```

I've already tried `EXTRA_CFLAG += -S` with no luck.

So is there any way to avoid creating debug info in my object files while building with kbuild?

Comment: You can alter one of the `KBUILD_XXX` variables which is the main compile setting.  `KBUILD_CFLAGS := $(filter-out "-g",$KBUILD_CFLAGS)` or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried turning off CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO?

Look for it in 'Kernel Hacking' -> 'Compile-time checks and compiler options' -> 'Compile the kernel with debug info' in menuconfig.

Comment: I'm building single module out-of-tree so i can't do `make menuconfig`. Is it possible to turn off CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO in module makefile?

Comment: No, but when you're building a module you still have a kernel source tree, with configuration so you can turn it off there.

Comment: I've edited .config in kernel source tree with `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=n` - that didn't help.